# How to undo/revert the exclusion of a file that has been added to .git/info/exclude

Tags: git

**Problem:**

I have a file excluded in `.git/info/exclude` and want to revert this exclusion and re-track the file.

**Background:**

I had a file that is constantly being changed locally for which I did not want to commit the changes, nor I wanted to add to my project's `.gitignore`. So I added it to the project's `.git/info/exclude` list, which worked fine, until I realised I could not update the file once the remote got updated.

`git version 2.24.0`

**What I have tried (and didn't work):**

1. Remove file name from `.git/info/exclude`

   1. `git checkout -- my-file.ext` - *nothing happened*
   2. `git update-index && git checkout -- my-file.ext` - *nothing happened*
   3. `git update-index --skip-worktree my-file.ext && git checkout -- my-file.ext` - *nothing happened*
   4. `rm my-file.ext && git checkout -- my-file.ext` - *file got removed, but no new file has arrived*
   5. `git reset --hard origin/my-branch` - *just for the sake of it, but nothing happened*
   6. manually updated the file and tried to force track it `git add my-file.ext -f` *nothing changed in git stage*
   7. `git update-index --really-refresh` - *this flag just felt like it would help :) but no changes*
   8. `git update-index --force-write-index` - *now I was just trying random stuff, no changes*
   9. `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged my-file.ext` - *no changes*

If I run `git status --ignored`, *the file is not part of the ignored list*

What am I missing here?

Comment: *So I added [the file's name] to the project's `.git/info/exclude` list ...* This has *no effect at all* on a tracked file (which this was). I think you *also* set the `--assume-unchanged` or `skip-worktree` flag on the copy of the file that was in the index; that's what had an effect. All you needed to do was run `git update-index --no-<whatever-flag>`, really.

Comment: @torek indeed I must have also added the `--assume-unchanged` flag to the files, but that should have been reversed with 9. which didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What ended up working for me was to:

1. Remove file name from `.git/info/exclude`
2. Remove the file from git cache `git rm -r --cached my-file.ext`
3. Unstaged the changes with `git reset`
4. Removed the local file with `rm my-file.ext`
5. Check-out the file again `git checkout my-file.ext`.

I am pretty sure that steps 3-5 could be replaced with a `git reset --hard`, but didn't test it.